# Talking to a demo Exchange Server 2007

Tags: web-services, soap, amazon-ec2, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I would like to test a trivial SOAP app against Microsoft Exchange 2007 (or 2010) webservices. Is there any demo server on the internet available? My problem is, that I have no 64-Bit machine around here to install a server for myself.

The 2003 server, which is hanging around at the office isn't suitable for my needs (Exchange Web Services)...

Is it a good solution to grab an Amazon EC2 account and install Exchange there?

Comment: did this work for you? do thay have a free EWS? what are the other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give mail2web.com a try. You can have a free Exchange account there, not sure if they give you access to EWS.

Or you can look at those Exchange hosting sites.

Answer (score 2):

The hosting provider 123Together has an Exchange 2010 OWA demo on their site:

http://www.123together.com/d/exchange_hosting_demo.xhtml

They link to the client access server:

https://owa10.123together.com/

And provide the following credentials:

Username: demo10@owatest10.123together.com
Password: demo123!

If you access https://owa10.123together.com/ews/exchange.asmx using the above username and password, you should be able to authenticate, and access Services.wsdl.  The demo page notes that sending from this account is disabled, other functionality may be restricted as well.

Answer (score 1):

on msdn there are virtual harddisks for Exchange2007sp1 and 2010 also

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53f7382a-3664-4de3-8303-31e514d69f02&displaylang=en#Requirements
you may download by this link.